# How to determine direction of arrival, given TDoA?

Tags: trigonometry, localization, triangulation

Given the location of three receivers (say, for instance, sound receivers) and the time at which each receiver “heard” some signal, I’d like to determine the direction of the signal relative to the receivers (i.e. the “Direction of Arrival”).

For my purposes, we can assume the receivers and the source are on the surface of the Earth, and we can ignore the curvature of the Earth, if necessary. There’s some information out there, but nothing particularly detailed with regards to implementing something concrete.

What are the formulas necessary to compute the direction of the source?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to locate an unknown point using the TDOA method of Trilateration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367330/how-to-locate-an-unknown-point-using-the-tdoa-method-of-trilateration)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722021/trilateration-using-tdoa?rq=1